# Text replace with emoticon on user description post in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I have this script made in javascript that replaces the text with an emoticon and works ok when I write in textarea ':)' '<3',etc.

But when I write a post and save it with this description " :) " I want the emoticon to appear instead of the text " :) "

The line that show's the description of saved post:

```
<p class="ptext msg_wrap" id="message"><?php echo $row['post_description']; ?>
```

Javascript Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map = {
   "<3": "\u2764\uFE0F",
   "</3": "\uD83D\uDC94",
   ":D": "\uD83D\uDE00",
   ":)": "\uD83D\uDE03",
   ";)": "\uD83D\uDE09",
   ":(": "\uD83D\uDE12",
   ":p": "\uD83D\uDE1B",
   ";p": "\uD83D\uDE1C",
   ":'(": "\uD83D\uDE22"
 };
 function escapeSpecialChars(regex) {
   return regex.replace(/([()[{*+.$^\\|?])/g, '\\$1');
 }
  document.getElementById('message').oninput = function() {
   for (var i in map) {
     var regex = new RegExp(escapeSpecialChars(i), 'gim');
     this.value = this.value = this.value.replace(regex, map[i]);
   }
 };

</script>
```

Comment: Change the `p` to an `input` so that it can have proper `input` events and it seemw to work perfectly.

Comment: Can you show me how please?

Answer (score 0):

You have written the JS function for `oninput` event.  Which means, it will look for input to trigger the change but you are assigning the text in a paragraph with `<p>` while loading it dynamically from db.  Either change the `<p>` to `<input>` or better yet, change your event to `onLoad`.

Comment: I have change'it from oninput to onLoad as you mentioned and is not showing the emoticon only text after refreshing the page.

Comment: can you post a fiddle?